# Sorting pair not working

Tags: c++, sorting, std-pair

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

pair<char[300],int> list[10000];

int main()
{
    char a[300],b[20000];
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int d=1; d<=n; d++)
    {
        list[d].second = 0;
    }
    int k=0;
    for(int d=1; d<=n; d++)
    {
        cin >> a;
        bool masuk=false;
        for(int e=1; e<=k;e++)
        {
            if (strcmp (a,list[e].first) == 0) 
            {
                masuk = true;
                list[e].second++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!(masuk))
        {
            k++;
            strcpy(list[k].first,a);
            list[k].second++;
        }
        cin.getline(b,256);
    }
    sort(list+1,list+k+1);
    for(int e =1; e<=k; e++)
    {
        cout << list[e].first << " " << list[e].second << endl;
    }
}
```

if i input

```
3
Spain Donna Elvira
England Jane Doe
Spain Donna Anna
```

i want it to output

```
England 1
Spain 2
```

but it output

```
Spain 2
England 1
```

isn't sort suppose to sort the first ? but it doesn't seems to work. i tried this on Dev C++ and it output correct, but when tried this on ideone it output wrong

Please help me, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: DevC++ is an outdated piece of crap, by the way. I suggest you switch to a better IDE, like Code::Blocks.

Comment: ok, but that still doesn't answer my question. how do i use sort on pair ?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Looks like a few people are trying to resurrect it...oddly enough: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B  Also note that Eclipse CDT (http://eclipse.org/cdt/) is a capable C++ environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things here that beat me:

1. Why are you using an array of std::pair to emulate the behaviour of a std::map?
2. Why do you start indexing at 1 instead of 0?

Anyway, std::sort takes a third argument, as Max Lybbert already mentioned. That argument is a pointer to a sorting function. This one works in your case:

```
bool mysort(std::pair<const char*, int> a, std::pair<const char*,int> b) {
    return (strcmp(a.first, b.first) < 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised you aren't getting a compiler error.  `std::sort` has no idea how to compare the elements in your array.  You need to pass that information in as `std::sort`'s thrid argument (as a pointer to a function or as a functor).

Comment: Re: *"std::sort has no idea how to compare the elements in your array"* -- Sure it does, although it's probably not what one wants.  It does a comparison of the first element, which is an array(which results in a pointer comparison), followed by an int comparison if necessary.